# why is my ajax GET data making a strange JSON object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, knockout.js

WARNING: possibly a dumb question.

I have an ajax get request like so:

```
$.getJSON("/recruiting/countries/all/", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (name, key) {
        var dropdownCountry = new DropdownCountry();
        dropdownCountry.name = name;
        dropdownCountry.key = key;
        self.orgCountryDdl.push(dropdownCountry);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(self.orgCountryDdl()));
});
```

it hits a url and has a list of countries: name and key.

I am trying to assign the data and eventually populate a knockout js observable array for a list of countries. The other javascript code that is references in this GET request:

```
var DropdownCountry = function (name, key) {
    this.name = name;
    this.key = key;
};

function UserRecruitingViewModel(apiBaseUrl, userId) {
     var self =this;
     //...snip...
     //ddl country stuff
     self.orgCountryDdl = ko.observableArray();
     self.selectedOrgCountry = ko.observable();
     var DropdownCountry = function (name, key) {
        this.name = name;
         this.key = key;
     };
     self.selectedOrgCountry = ko.observable();
              ///..get request in here...
 };
```

in the alert I have I am seeing this data coming back:

```
 [
{"name":0,"key":{"Id":1,"Name":"Albania"}}
,{"name":1,"key":{"Id":2,"Name":"Algeria"}}
,{"name":2,"key":{"Id":3,"Name":"American Samoa"}}
,{"name":3,"key":{"Id":4,"Name":"Andorra"}}
,{"name":4,"key":{"Id":5,"Name":"Angola"}}
,{"name":5,"key":{"Id":6,"Name":"Anguilla"}}
,{"name":6,"key":{"Id":7,"Name":"Antarctica"}}
...snip...
]
```

What is going on, and what is the cleanest way to get this into a knockout observable array?

Sorry: desired result is this data:

```
 [
{"Id":1,"Name":"Albania"}
,{"Id":2,"Name":"Algeria"}
,{"Id":3,"Name":"American Samoa"}
...snip...
]
```

I actually figured it out on accident:

```
$.getJSON("/recruiting/countries/all/", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (name, key) {
        var dropdownCountry = new DropdownCountry();
        dropdownCountry.name = key.Name;
        dropdownCountry.key = key.Id;
        self.orgCountryDdl.push(dropdownCountry);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(self.orgCountryDdl()));
});
```

The second function variable had the data I wanted. Can someone explain why that is? I am pretty newbish to ajax calls, so I wouldn't even know what to google.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: And why do you need to declare this `self.selectedOrgCountry = ko.observable();` two times?

Comment: Desired result is an object that has key: "1", Name: "country name". Am I declaring the ko array twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.each` is defined as follows:](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

> jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )

Which means that when you call:

```
$.each(data, function (name, key) { ...
```

You are iterating over each element in the data array. The `name` parameter above will be set to the current index of the element it is iterating over, and `key` is  the value. jQuery does *not* read the parameter names and fill in the values.

What you're looking for is this

```
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
  var name = element.name;
  var key = element.key;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for posted some reference. See my edit, I figured this one out on accident and wasn't sure why it worked.